# Creating a heightmap from hillshade/radar data?

Tags: dem, elevation, terrain, radar

So there are several threads explaining how to create a hillshade map from DEM. Does anyone know of a method to do the opposite? Essentially all I have is unidirectional radar data which functions essentially the same as hillshade. Are there any tools available, in ARCGis pro or otherwise, that extrapolate, even roughly, height data from a hillshade like image? The 'light' is essentially coming from the west here.

[image: Example of data]